# Getting error Unrecognized font family 'din-next-lt-w23-regular' in react-native 0.61.4 only for iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

i am using fonts in my app. So i need to add the font **din-next-lt-w23-regular** in my app. But i am getting error in iOS i.e., `Unrecognized font family 'din-next-lt-w23-regular'`. I added **.ttf** files in **ios/Resources** and **info.plist**.
Here is my code
**react-native.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'], 
};
```

Screenshot:-
[image]

Comment: have you checked this https://medium.com/@kswanie21/custom-fonts-in-react-native-tutorial-for-ios-android-76ceeaa0eb78

Comment: @GauravRoy thanku for your reply. I tried this one https://medium.com/@kswanie21/custom-fonts-in-react-native-tutorial-for-ios-android-76ceeaa0eb78 but no use.

Comment: have you tried the third step of adding fonts in bundle resources in xcode?

Comment: s i did but getting same error...

Answer (score 1):

Check the **PostScript name** of the font, it is what IOS uses to recognize fonts.
 You can check the **postscript name** of a font file in Font book.

Here is a good guide to add fonts to react-native https://medium.com/@mehran.khan/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4

Comment: @ B. Mohammad Thanku for your reply. I already tried this one https://medium.com/@mehran.khan/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4 but no use.

Comment: yes, it's working i used the PostScript name in my file. Thanku.